# SAP HANA out of memory on UNION

Tags: hana

I have a table with 28mn records which on union (on a graphical calc view on HANA 2 SP2) with a view returning 5000 records goes into memory dumps. I've tried a SQL union all and it still doesn't work. There is no logic in the union view.

A select top 1000 on the table returns data in <1s and the the view with 5k records brings back data in 2s. When I union these 2 with no logic whatsoever - even after switching the aggregation node to projection, it still runs out of memory. What am I missing here?

> transaction rolled back by an internal error: Allocation failed ; $size$=2048; $name$=SearchAlloc; $type$=pool; $inuse_count$=11184979; $allocated_size$=20190632592; $alignment$=16

Comment: A good first step to understand the difference in the execution of queries is to review the EXPLAIN PLAN and the PlanViz (trace) for both statements.

My guess here is that the SELECT TOP 1000 only is applied to the final result set and that the UNION ALL of the two sub-queries/calc. views needs to get fully materialised before that. If that is the case, you might consider limiting the data sizes before the UNION operation.

Answer (score 0):

Especially "union", but also "union all" can consume a lot of memory, e.g. When early materializations are used internally. I had a case a few days ago, where a "union all" consumed 130gb temp memory. After splitting the union all into two statements the max memory consumption went down to 11gb!
Try this approach if your application permits it. Follow Lars advice and compare planviz for union all and the split statements.

Check following SAP Note for reference:
https://launchpad.support.sap.com/services/pdf/notes/1999997/E

19...."Avgoid UNION ALL, UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT

These operations can't be handled by the column engine and so optimizations like late materialization (SAP Note 1975448) are not possible. As a consequence the memory requirements can significantly increase. Therefore you should use alternative whenever possible (e.g. OR instead of UNION or UNION ALL)...“

As usual, it all depends on your use case etc.